# Multiplicar valor no array

Tags: array, java-processing

Como eu faço para multiplicar os elementos de um array? o que estou fazendo de errado?

Por exemplo, se eu tenho:

```
int numbers[]={1,2,2,4,5,6};
```

e a minha card_block é 2, o restutado daria 1x4x5x6=120;

```
int countCards(int [] cards, int BLOCK_CARD){
  int quant=0;
  int count =0;
  for (int i=0; i<cards.length; i++){
   if(cards[i]!=BLOCK_CARD)
  count=cards[i];
  count=count*cards[i];

   quant=count;
  }
  return quant;
}
```

Comment: Qual é a logica que está a tentar aplicar ? Cada vez que está na carta bloqueada é suposto multiplicar pela ultima antes da bloqueada ou simplesmente ignorar a carta ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma mais enxuta seria usar os recursos de Java 8. Você poderia usar Streams e seus operadores.

```
 int countCards(int [] cards, int BLOCK_CARD){
     return IntStream.of(cards)
                .filter(s -> s != BLOCK_CARD)
                .reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
 }
```

Apenas lambrando, usar streams inclui a própria stream que deriva de uma coleção, em seguida as operações intermediárias que sempre resultam em uma nova stream e a operação terminal, que finaliza e retorna um resultado.

Um link com uma visão geral sobre Stream você pode ver [aqui](https://biaintech.wordpress.com/2018/12/24/java8-streams/).

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
  int countCards(int [] cards, int BLOCK_CARD){
  int quant=0;
  int count =1;
  for (int i=0; i<cards.length; i++){
   if(cards[i]!=BLOCK_CARD){

  count=count*cards[i];
}
   quant=count;
  }
  return quant;
}
```

Comment: Valeu, era isso mesmo!